# Multiple images from foreach loop in carousel doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter

This code is not working properly. It shows result in each single thumbnail instead of showing in single thumbnail and does not move.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">                            
      <ul class="thumbnails">                           
        <li class="span2">
          <?php foreach ($oneimg->result() as $oneimg):?> 
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="<?php echo HTTP_IMAGES_PATH_UPLOADIMAGE; ?><?php echo $oneimg->images ?>" 
                 alt=""  class="img-responsive" style="height:180px; width:100%"/>                                      
          </div>
          <?php  endforeach;   ?> 
        </li>                                     
      </ul>          
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: please post your controller code to more explanation about your code

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    foreach ($oneimg as $oneimg_new)
    {
        ?>
        <div class="thumbnail">

            <img src="<?php echo HTTP_IMAGES_PATH_UPLOADIMAGE; ?><?php echo $oneimg_new['images']?>"
                 alt=""  class="img-responsive" style="height:180px; width:100%"/>

        </div>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: __Why should OP try this??__  And please explain what changes you have done to make it correct??

Comment: @AshishAware if my answer helpful grateful by accepting it or Vote it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for answer
but i have solved it and it works perfect here is the solution

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

   <?php $i = 1; ?>
        <?php foreach ($oneimg->result_array() as $oneimg): ?>
        <?php $item_class = ($i == 1) ? 'item active' : 'item'; ?>
            <div class="<?php echo $item_class; ?>">
                  <a href="#">
                            <img src="<?php echo HTTP_IMAGES_PATH_UPLOADIMAGE; ?><?php echo $oneimg['images']; ?>" 
                                alt=""  class="img-responsive" style="height:400px; width:100%" />
                  </a>
            </div>
        <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 

</div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```